# How to insert a new row in MySQL where primary key column is Unique and Random Number

Tags: mysql, random, unique, insert-into, unique-key

I have a table with a primary index column that is:

`ID | mediumint(8) | UNSIGNED ZEROFILL | PRIMARY`

I have various columns of data to insert into the table and while I am doing it I want to also have the ID column created as a unique and random number between **15000001** and **15999999**.

I have seen a number of ways to use MySQL to select random values based on what already exists in a table, but I have not been able to find what an `INSERT INTO` query statement would look like to do this.

**Notes:**

1. The number becomes a confirmation number and I do not want it
   sequentially incremented.
2. I can easily do this through a PHP (random number generation) and a MySQL test for the existence of the number LOOP
3. just wondering if it could be streamlined via a single MySQL query.
4. I recognize the potential for "performance" issues -- but there will not be any as I will never reach 999,999 rows in the 15 range in my app

Comment: Why do you random primary keys?

Comment: The number becomes a confirmation number and I do not want it sequentially incremented.

Comment: You could just generate the confirmation number separately. You'd still have to check for collisions with the uniqueness requirement; but the primary key should be independent of that. I'd go with your "generate in code and check against the database solution"; to reduce the potential performance hit, you could generate a number of candidates (for use as a pool for pending inserts) at once and see which (if any) are found before using.

Comment: Right @Uussedo -- from the responses thus far it looks like this is not do-able so I am going to write a PHP/MySQL Select loop to solve

Comment: See the edit to my previous comment about reducing performance concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Why use random number? 
AUTO_INCREMENT should be the solution 
ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: The number becomes a confirmation number and I do not want it sequentially incremented.